# Identify Route Locations tool to display Z coordinate

Tags: tools, arcgis-10.6, basic-license-level

Identify Route Locations tool working with routing which is connected to M coordinate. 

Is there a ArcGIS tool which display route location with Z coordinate? It could be similar aproach - identify nearest vertexes and interpolate Z coordinate.

[image: IRL_Results_example]